# How can I put a SVG image code into HTML file without the usage of img tag?

Tags: html, svg

I have a SVG image. I know I can use it in an image tag but this way I cannot style the path tags of the svg.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="512px" height="398px" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g><path style="opacity:0.993" fill="#000000" d="M 235.5,-0.5 C 248.833,-0.5 262.167,-0.5 275.5,-0.5C 353.784,10.624 408.951,52.2907 441,124.5C 468.343,202.773 455.01,273.107 401,335.5C 366.395,370.719 324.561,391.386 275.5,397.5C 262.167,397.5 248.833,397.5 235.5,397.5C 147.918,384.421 90.4184,335.755 63,251.5C 44.1335,169.779 65.6335,100.946 127.5,45C 159.111,19.4077 195.111,4.24107 235.5,-0.5 Z M 252.5,88.5 C 262.79,88.2893 268.623,93.2893 270,103.5C 270.667,148.5 270.667,193.5 270,238.5C 269.085,247.249 264.252,252.249 255.5,253.5C 246.748,252.249 241.915,247.249 241,238.5C 240.333,193.5 240.333,148.5 241,103.5C 241.713,95.9701 245.546,90.9701 252.5,88.5 Z M 253.5,278.5 C 268.106,280.706 272.606,288.706 267,302.5C 259.333,310.5 251.667,310.5 244,302.5C 238.615,290.955 241.781,282.955 253.5,278.5 Z"/></g>
<g><path style="opacity:0.959" fill="#000000" d="M -0.5,221.5 C -0.5,206.167 -0.5,190.833 -0.5,175.5C 5.14748,123.215 24.3141,76.5481 57,35.5C 64.1348,28.503 71.9681,27.6696 80.5,33C 85.9216,39.2833 86.7549,46.1166 83,53.5C 29.9793,120.615 16.9793,194.948 44,276.5C 53.1732,301.196 66.1732,323.53 83,343.5C 87.6577,358.723 82.1577,366.557 66.5,367C 64.0506,366.275 61.7173,365.275 59.5,364C 25.3602,322.542 5.36016,275.042 -0.5,221.5 Z"/></g>
<g><path style="opacity:0.959" fill="#000000" d="M 511.5,175.5 C 511.5,190.833 511.5,206.167 511.5,221.5C 505.64,275.042 485.64,322.542 451.5,364C 441.159,369.772 432.992,367.606 427,357.5C 426.19,352.743 426.524,348.076 428,343.5C 481.02,276.389 494.02,202.055 467,120.5C 457.827,95.8038 444.827,73.4705 428,53.5C 422.821,36.6833 428.987,28.85 446.5,30C 449.562,31.0608 452.062,32.8941 454,35.5C 486.686,76.5481 505.853,123.215 511.5,175.5 Z"/></g>
</svg>
```

So this is the code inside my svg image. I want it inside the HTML file.

I've tried to put it without the xml and doctype tags of course. But without success.

```html
<svg class="icon handbrake" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="512px" height="398px" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <path style="opacity:0.993" fill="#000000" d="M 235.5,-0.5 C 248.833,-0.5 262.167,-0.5 275.5,-0.5C 353.784,10.624 408.951,52.2907 441,124.5C 468.343,202.773 455.01,273.107 401,335.5C 366.395,370.719 324.561,391.386 275.5,397.5C 262.167,397.5 248.833,397.5 235.5,397.5C 147.918,384.421 90.4184,335.755 63,251.5C 44.1335,169.779 65.6335,100.946 127.5,45C 159.111,19.4077 195.111,4.24107 235.5,-0.5 Z M 252.5,88.5 C 262.79,88.2893 268.623,93.2893 270,103.5C 270.667,148.5 270.667,193.5 270,238.5C 269.085,247.249 264.252,252.249 255.5,253.5C 246.748,252.249 241.915,247.249 241,238.5C 240.333,193.5 240.333,148.5 241,103.5C 241.713,95.9701 245.546,90.9701 252.5,88.5 Z M 253.5,278.5 C 268.106,280.706 272.606,288.706 267,302.5C 259.333,310.5 251.667,310.5 244,302.5C 238.615,290.955 241.781,282.955 253.5,278.5 Z"/>
     <path style="opacity:0.959" fill="#000000" d="M -0.5,221.5 C -0.5,206.167 -0.5,190.833 -0.5,175.5C 5.14748,123.215 24.3141,76.5481 57,35.5C 64.1348,28.503 71.9681,27.6696 80.5,33C 85.9216,39.2833 86.7549,46.1166 83,53.5C 29.9793,120.615 16.9793,194.948 44,276.5C 53.1732,301.196 66.1732,323.53 83,343.5C 87.6577,358.723 82.1577,366.557 66.5,367C 64.0506,366.275 61.7173,365.275 59.5,364C 25.3602,322.542 5.36016,275.042 -0.5,221.5 Z"/>
     <path style="opacity:0.959" fill="#000000" d="M 511.5,175.5 C 511.5,190.833 511.5,206.167 511.5,221.5C 505.64,275.042 485.64,322.542 451.5,364C 441.159,369.772 432.992,367.606 427,357.5C 426.19,352.743 426.524,348.076 428,343.5C 481.02,276.389 494.02,202.055 467,120.5C 457.827,95.8038 444.827,73.4705 428,53.5C 422.821,36.6833 428.987,28.85 446.5,30C 449.562,31.0608 452.062,32.8941 454,35.5C 486.686,76.5481 505.853,123.215 511.5,175.5 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Just to be clear, I don't want this: `<img src="assets/icons/handbrake.svg">`

Comment: Both codeblocks display an icon when testing via codepen - though I would prefer the second one. Do you have a black background-color?

Comment: Added a Web Component example to my answer; easier than using SVG ``<use>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a lot of mileage with the [`<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)

In this example I have removed the `fill` and `style` from your SVG and given the groups a classname so we can target them. The SVG is embedded on-page but hidden with CSS.

Elsewhere in the page I have used this SVG multiple times and restyled each instance to illustrate how it could work for you.

```css
:root {
  --g1opacity: 0.993;
  --g2opacity: 0.959;
  --g3opacity: 0.959;
}

#mysvg {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#mysvg .g1 {
  opacity: var(--g1opacity);
}

#mysvg .g2 {
  opacity: var(--g2opacity);
}

#mysvg .g3 {
  opacity: var(--g3opacity);
}

.mysvg1 {
  width: 200px;
  fill: red;
}

.mysvg2 {
  width: 100px;
  fill: blue;
}

.mysvg_bounds {
  display:block;
  max-width:300px;
  padding:10px 10px 2em;
  color: orange;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  resize: both; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mysvg_bounds svg {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  fill: currentColor;
}

svg:hover {
  --g2opacity: 0.2;
  --g3opacity: 0.2;
  fill: purple;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="512px" height="398px" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g class="g1"><path d="M 235.5,-0.5 C 248.833,-0.5 262.167,-0.5 275.5,-0.5C 353.784,10.624 408.951,52.2907 441,124.5C 468.343,202.773 455.01,273.107 401,335.5C 366.395,370.719 324.561,391.386 275.5,397.5C 262.167,397.5 248.833,397.5 235.5,397.5C 147.918,384.421 90.4184,335.755 63,251.5C 44.1335,169.779 65.6335,100.946 127.5,45C 159.111,19.4077 195.111,4.24107 235.5,-0.5 Z M 252.5,88.5 C 262.79,88.2893 268.623,93.2893 270,103.5C 270.667,148.5 270.667,193.5 270,238.5C 269.085,247.249 264.252,252.249 255.5,253.5C 246.748,252.249 241.915,247.249 241,238.5C 240.333,193.5 240.333,148.5 241,103.5C 241.713,95.9701 245.546,90.9701 252.5,88.5 Z M 253.5,278.5 C 268.106,280.706 272.606,288.706 267,302.5C 259.333,310.5 251.667,310.5 244,302.5C 238.615,290.955 241.781,282.955 253.5,278.5 Z"/></g>
<g class="g2"><path d="M -0.5,221.5 C -0.5,206.167 -0.5,190.833 -0.5,175.5C 5.14748,123.215 24.3141,76.5481 57,35.5C 64.1348,28.503 71.9681,27.6696 80.5,33C 85.9216,39.2833 86.7549,46.1166 83,53.5C 29.9793,120.615 16.9793,194.948 44,276.5C 53.1732,301.196 66.1732,323.53 83,343.5C 87.6577,358.723 82.1577,366.557 66.5,367C 64.0506,366.275 61.7173,365.275 59.5,364C 25.3602,322.542 5.36016,275.042 -0.5,221.5 Z"/></g>
<g class="g3"><path d="M 511.5,175.5 C 511.5,190.833 511.5,206.167 511.5,221.5C 505.64,275.042 485.64,322.542 451.5,364C 441.159,369.772 432.992,367.606 427,357.5C 426.19,352.743 426.524,348.076 428,343.5C 481.02,276.389 494.02,202.055 467,120.5C 457.827,95.8038 444.827,73.4705 428,53.5C 422.821,36.6833 428.987,28.85 446.5,30C 449.562,31.0608 452.062,32.8941 454,35.5C 486.686,76.5481 505.853,123.215 511.5,175.5 Z"/></g>
</svg>
<!-- above SVG is hidden off-screen -->
<!-- We can use copies of it below -->

<h3>Using the <tt>&lt;use&gt;</tt> element</h3>

<svg class="mysvg1" viewBox="0 0 512 398">
   <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="mysvg2" viewBox="0 0 512 398">
   <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
</svg>

<div class="mysvg_bounds">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 398">
     <use xlink:href="#mysvg"></use>
  </svg>
  Resize me.
</div>
```

Comment: Just note that if you’re going to use an SVG sprite, make sure to include the sprite at the beginning of the body tag and add inline styles to hide it. I typically use this: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="height: 0; position: absolute; width: 0" focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" aria-hidden="true">`. If your sprite is going to contain multiple icons, you’ll need to wrap each one in a `<symbol>` tag with a unique ID and the original icon’s `viewBox` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can add SVGs directly to HTML. I would just include the `viewBox` attribute and `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` to keep the aspect ratio consistent.

```css
.handbrake {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  display: block;
  fill: currentColor;
  height: auto;
  transition: color 180ms ease;
  width: 200px;
}

.handbrake:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon handbrake" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 398" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <g fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M235.5-.5h40C353.8 10.6 409 52.3 441 124.5c27.3 78.3 14 148.6-40 211a207 207 0 0 1-125.5 62h-40c-87.6-13-145-61.7-172.5-146-18.9-81.7 2.6-150.6 64.5-206.5a206.6 206.6 0 0 1 108-45.5Zm17 89c10.3-.2 16.1 4.8 17.5 15 .7 45 .7 90 0 135-1 8.7-5.7 13.7-14.5 15-8.8-1.3-13.6-6.3-14.5-15-.7-45-.7-90 0-135 .7-7.5 4.5-12.5 11.5-15Zm1 190c14.6 2.2 19.1 10.2 13.5 24-7.7 8-15.3 8-23 0-5.4-11.5-2.2-19.5 9.5-24Z"/>
    <path d="M-.5 221.5v-46c5.6-52.3 24.8-99 57.5-140 7.1-7 15-7.8 23.5-2.5A17.1 17.1 0 0 1 83 53.5c-53 67.1-66 141.4-39 223a226 226 0 0 0 39 67c4.7 15.2-.8 23-16.5 23.5-2.4-.7-4.8-1.7-7-3a264.9 264.9 0 0 1-60-142.5Zm512-46v46a264.9 264.9 0 0 1-60 142.5c-10.3 5.8-18.5 3.6-24.5-6.5a29 29 0 0 1 1-14c53-67.1 66-141.4 39-223a226 226 0 0 0-39-67c-5.2-16.8 1-24.6 18.5-23.5 3 1 5.6 2.9 7.5 5.5 32.7 41 51.9 87.7 57.5 140Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

FYI I ran your SVG through https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

### Create an SVG *client-side*

With your own modern standard Web Component `<svg-handbrake>` you can use as many instances as you want, without the (oldskool) SVG `<use>`

```html
<svg-handbrake fill="red"></svg-handbrake>
<svg-handbrake fill="blue"></svg-handbrake>
<svg-handbrake fill="orange"></svg-handbrake>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-handbrake", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      // unique ID so each instance has its own styles (no need for shadowDOM)
      let id = "handbrake_" + crypto.randomUUID();
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<style>#${id}{fill:${this.getAttribute("fill")};cursor:pointer}`+
        `#${id}:hover .sides {opacity:0.5;fill:grey}</style>`+
        `<svg id="${id}" viewBox="-10 -10 540 420" width="150px" style="background:pink">` +
          `<path class="circle" fill-rule="evenodd" d="m236-1c13 0 26 0 40 0 78 12 133 53 165 126 27 78 14 148-40 211-35 35-76 55-125 62-14 0-27 0-40 0-88-14-146-62-173-146-19-82 3-151 65-207 31-26 67-41 108-46zm17 90c10-1 16 4 17 15 1 45 1 90 0 135-1 8-6 13-14 15-9-2-14-7-15-15-1-45-1-90 0-135 1-8 5-13 12-15zm1 190c14 2 19 10 13 24-8 8-15 8-23 0-5-12-2-20 10-24z"/>` +
          `<path class="sides" d="m-1 222c0-16 0-31 0-46 6-53 25-99 58-140 7-7 15-8 24-3 5 6 6 13 2 21-53 67-66 141-39 223 9 24 22 47 39 67 5 15-1 23-16 23-3-1-5-2-7-3-35-41-55-89-61-142zm513-46c0 15 0 30 0 46-6 53-26 101-60 142-11 6-19 4-25-6-1-5 0-10 1-14 53-68 66-142 39-223-9-25-22-48-39-67-5-17 1-25 19-24 3 1 5 3 7 6 33 41 52 87 58 140z"/>` +
          `</svg>`;
    }
  })
</script>
```

### Load an external SVG

You can **inject** a SVG with the `<load-file>` Web Component I wrote:

Full Dev.to blog post:
https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

All code required:

```js
// Define <load-file> Web Component once, doesn't matter when it is defined
customElements.define("load-file", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text();
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"));
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...this.shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
```

```css
svg,load-file {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- USE Web Component : replace <load-file> with SVG -->
<load-file replaceWith src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></load-file>

<load-file src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
<!-- create <load-file> with shadowDOM, inject <style> -->
  <style shadowRoot>
    path:nth-child(2n+2) {
      fill: GREEN; /* shadowDOM style does NOT style global DOM */
    }
  </style>
</load-file>
```